# Avoid entering double quotes from start & ending of a string

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

In a database, I have a string that contains "default" written in it. I just want to replace that default with 0. I have something like:

```
select * from tblname where test = 'default'
```

I do not want quotes in the replacement for "default".

I want

```
select * from tblname where test = 0
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you not just change it how you have demonstrated?

Comment: please tell us which programming language/system and whicht database system you are using.

Comment: Not sure the re-tagging is quite right? He was after C# help initially so maybe we need to explain the perils of generated SQL not re-tag to SQL?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the field `test` is of a text type (varchar, char, or the like).

First: Update the table to contain '0' where it contains 'default'.

```
UPDATE tblname SET test = '0' WHERE test = 'default'
```

Then: Select all rows with '0' in them. You can't leave off the quotes, because they are part of the SQL syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE test = '0'
```

To be able to leave off the quotes, you must turn the field into a numeric one (int, float or the like).

Comment: Even after reading your answer, it took me a while to understand the question. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better using format strings

```
string myVar = "0";
string sql = String.Format(@"select * from tblname where test = \"{0}\"", myVar);
```

You should also ask yourself why you are generating inline SQL on the fly and not using stored procedures as this is how SQL injection attacks can occur unless you sanitize the input.

Comment: Since the re-tagging this looks way off topic but I'm fairly sure was the point of the original question. The merits of the original question should be discussed not editing the post and assuming what the original poster meant or wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do in order to effect a simple string replacement;, however, I strongly suggest that you look into parameterization, to provide both injection  safety and query-plan re-use.

Parameters also benefit by avoiding the quote issue - so just replace `'default'` with (for example) `@p1` and you're sorted. This replace can be:

```
-- TSQL
REPLACE(@cmd, '''default''', '@p1')
```

or

```
// C#
.Replace(@"'default'", @"@p1")
```

From C#, this would a `DbCommand` with parameters; from T-SQL you might consider `sp_ExecuteSQL`. Either way, you'd want to end up with:

```
select * from tblname where test = @p1
```

And supply @p1 as the parameter. So from C#:

```
DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.Value = 0; // etc
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Or from TSQL:

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @cmd, N'@p1 varchar(50)', 0
```

(replace `varchar(50)` with the correct type)